# How to find a certain XML-Element and add it as a new one?

Tags: php, xml, dom, appendchild

Hi I looped through an XML Document and searching for specific Word (that works) and after that i would like to a a certain Element if the word is included in that part.

```
<product>
    <title>TestProduct</title>
    <Specifications>
      <item name="Specifications1">Test</item>
      <item name="Specifications2">Hello World</item>
    </Specifications>
    <body>
      <item name="Color">Black</item>
    </body>
 </product>
```

I tried this:

```
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load('Test.xml');
# set up the xpath
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$append= $dom->getElementsByTagName('Text');
print_r($append);
foreach ($xpath->query("*[contains(., 'Test')]") as $item) {
    $element = $dom->createElement('ID', '123');
    $append->appendChild($element);
}    
?>
```

but it doesn't work can someone give me a hint? Tanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your trying to add the new element into the wrong place.  This combines the `getElementsByTagName` and the XPath into one loop and then adds the new element to any element it finds.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load('Test.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query("//*[contains(., 'Black')]") as $item) {
    $element = $dom->createElement('ID', '123');
    $item->appendChild($element);
}

echo $dom->saveXML();
```

See how the XPath finds any element which contains 'Test'.  Then it adds the new element to each element it finds.
The main thing that I have changed is you were adding the ID to `$append` and not `$item`.

If you wanted to just update the first instance of a particular piece of text...

```
$matchList = $xpath->query("//*[contains(text(), 'Black')]");
$element = $dom->createElement('ID', '123');
$matchList->item(0)->appendChild($element);
echo $dom->saveXML().PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: so i should add the element after the loop?

Comment: actually it doesn't add anything i don't know what to do

Comment: Have you got some XML to test this on?  It makes it a lot easier.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the sample XML so I can test my code?

Comment: i edited the code so i would like to match trough everything and get for example Black and if there is the Word Black in that product i would like to add an ID

Comment: OK - I was assuming the element had to be of type 'Text', I've changed the foreach to similar to what you were using in the first place.

Comment: it works fine but add ID to every Element it finds but i would like to add it only once? how is that possible? I need it only one time at the end of the product